Band Gap Calculation for conjugated polymers
How to calculate HOMO-LUMO band gap for conjugated polymers using Gaussian? is there any specific keyword for the same?
Based on the optimization output the Alpha occ eigenvalue (max) = -0.17661eV and the Alpha virt eigenvalue (min) = -0.11897eV. If we use these values we get band gap of 0.06e.V which we believe is too low for the conjugated polymers.
For the optimization calculation we used the B3LPY hybrid functional with 6-311G (d, p) Basis set.
